# Remove single quotes in list in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a DataFrame like this. `colA` contains list of items, however it's stored under quotes like this

```
data = [(("ID1", "['valA', 'valB']")), (("ID1", "[]")), (("ID1", "['valC']")), (("ID1", ""))]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ID", "colA"])
df.show()

+---+----------------+
| ID|            colA|
+---+----------------+
|ID1|['valA', 'valB']|
|ID2|              []|
|ID3|        ['valC']|
|ID4|                |
+---+----------------+
```

`colA` has blank and empty list values.

I want to clean this column, such that I have the following DataFrame

```
+---+------------+
| ID|        colA|
+---+------------+
|ID1|[valA, valB]|
|ID2|        null|
|ID3|      [valC]|
|ID4|        null|
+---+------------+
```

Comment: What should be the datatype of the result? Array of String? String?

Comment: anything could do, it could be array, list, comma separated

Comment: should it be `list('valA', 'valB')` or `'[valA, valB]'`?

Comment: this is what I wish for - [valA, valB], basically it's a list without single quotes for each item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps:

1. Remove starting `^['` or `|` ending `']$` brackets. `\` is for escaping, `^` for start of string, `$` for end of string
2. Turn empty lists `[]` into empty strings, again escaping with `\`
3. Remove empty strings
4. Split by `', '` or `','` to seperate elements, `?` means optional space

**Code**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

data = [(("ID1", "['valA', 'valB']")), (("ID1", "[]")), (("ID1", "['valC']")), (("ID1", ""))]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ID", "colA"])

df_2 \
  .withColumn('colA_2', f.regexp_replace('colA', "^\['|'\]$", '')) \
  .withColumn('colA_2', f.regexp_replace('colA_2', "\[\]", '')) \
  .withColumn('colA_2', f.when(f.col('colA_2') == "", None).otherwise(f.col('colA_2'))) \
  .withColumn('colA_2', f.split('colA_2', "', ?'"))
```

**Output**

```
df_2.show()

+---+----------------+------------+
| ID|            colA|      colA_2|
+---+----------------+------------+
|ID1|['valA', 'valB']|[valA, valB]|
|ID1|              []|        null|
|ID1|        ['valC']|      [valC]|
|ID1|                |        null|
+---+----------------+------------+
```

```
df_2.printSchema()

root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- colA: string (nullable = true)
 |-- colA_2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('colA', F.split(F.regexp_replace('colA', '[\[\]]', ''), ',')).show()
+---+-----------------+
| ID|             colA|
+---+-----------------+
|ID1|['valA',  'valB']|
|ID1|               []|
|ID1|         ['valC']|
|ID1|               []|
+---+-----------------+
```

Comment: but what if you get `['valA', 'fh,fd,df,fd', 'valC']` as input?

Comment: True and it should be null instead of `[]`, bad answer

Answer (score 1):

Not using spark, try something like that

```
df.replace({"": np.nan}, inplace=True)
df.colA[df.colA=="[]"]=np.nan
```